# Indexes in databases

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a few doubts about indexs in databases:

1. Suppose i have a table **'student**':

   ```
   id  name  age  class  roll_no
   1   vijay 24   12     1007
   2   vinay 25   10     1008
   ```

   if i write `select * from student where name='vijay';`

   1. If i have index on column name then it will search for index name in index table ? Can i check index table data how does it store data ?
   2. If i don't have index then it will search for only name column or entire row starting from first row's id, then name and so on.... and then second row ?
   3. Is indexes can be created on non unique column's ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html and https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 0):

Read here for more info on indexes.
http://postgresguide.com/performance/indexes.html

Edit: Rectified for postgresql

Google a bit before asking questions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for that. My bad